# Date format for DateColum in extjs editor grid

Tags: extjs, extjs3

My editor grid have DateColum as bellow

```
MyColumn1Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.DateColumn, {
    constructor: function(cfg) {
        cfg = cfg || {};
        MyColumn1Ui.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            header: 'Date',
            sortable: true,
            width: 100,
            dataIndex: 'DATE',
            format: 'm-d-Y',
            css: ' width: 94px !important;',
            id: 'date_col',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                name: 'USG_DATE',
                format: 'm-d-Y',
                maxLength: 50,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                id: 'date'
            }
        }, cfg));
    }
});
```

I need date as mm-dd-yyyy but my grid `afteredit` method give date as bellow format
`Wed Dec 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)` how can i get get date as mm-dd-yyyy.

NOTE: event i don't change date grid fire afteredit event because of change date format grid cell click

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
MyColumn1Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.DateColumn, {
constructor: function(cfg) {
    cfg = cfg || {};
    MyColumn1Ui.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
        header: 'Date',
        sortable: true,
        width: 100,
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format: 'm-d-Y',
        css: ' width: 94px !important;',
        id: 'date_col',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            name: 'USG_DATE',
            maxLength: 50,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            id: 'date'
        }
    }, cfg));
}
```

});